# Sistema de login do Facebook SDK 7.3 com o Unity 5.3

Tags: unity3d, facebook-sdk

Estou implementando o Facebook SDK no meu jogo criado no Unity e estou tendo muitos problemas.
Eu tentei implementar o sistema de login do Facebook:

```
FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" }, AuthCallBack);
```

So que os seguintes erros apareceram:

> **NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object UnityEngine.GUILayoutEntry.ApplyStyleSettings
> (UnityEngine.GUIStyle style) (at
> C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:507)
> UnityEngine.GUILayoutGroup.ApplyStyleSettings (UnityEngine.GUIStyle
> style) (at
> C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:626)
> UnityEngine.GUILayoutEntry.set_style (UnityEngine.GUIStyle value) (at
> C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:471)
> UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.BeginWindow (Int32 windowID,
> UnityEngine.GUIStyle style, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options) (at
> C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:91)
> UnityEngine.GUI.CallWindowDelegate (UnityEngine.WindowFunction func,
> Int32 id, UnityEngine.GUISkin _skin, Int32 forceRect, Single width,
> Single height, UnityEngine.GUIStyle style) (at
> C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUI.cs:1862)
>
> **ArgumentException: Getting control 0's position in a group with only 0 controls when doing Repaint**
> ArgumentException: Getting control
> 0's position in a group with only 0 controls when doing Repaint
> Aborting UnityEngine.GUILayoutGroup.GetNext () (at
> C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:656)
> UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.DoGetRect (Single minWidth, Single
> maxWidth, Single minHeight, Single maxHeight, UnityEngine.GUIStyle
> style, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options) (at
> C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:401)
> UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.GetRect (Single width, Single height,
> UnityEngine.GUIStyle style, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options) (at
> C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:375)
> UnityEngine.GUILayout.Space (Single pixels) (at
> C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayout.cs:247)
> Facebook.Unity.Editor.EditorFacebookMockDialog.OnGUIDialog (Int32
> windowId) (at
> Assets/FacebookSDK/SDK/Scripts/PlatformEditor/EditorFacebookMockDialog.cs:90)
> UnityEngine.GUI.CallWindowDelegate (UnityEngine.WindowFunction func,
> Int32 id, UnityEngine.GUISkin _skin, Int32 forceRect, Single width,
> Single height, UnityEngine.GUIStyle style) (at
> C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUI.cs:1869)

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer in English, but I had the same issue and Facebook is already aware of the bug:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/412005298997939/

They have a temporal workaround: in EditorFacebookMockDialog.cs add this to the begin of the OnGUI method:

```
if (this.modalStyle == null)
{
    this.modalRect = new Rect(10, 10, Screen.width - 20, Screen.height - 20);
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    texture.SetPixel(0, 0, new Color(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f));
    texture.Apply();
    this.modalStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.window);
    this.modalStyle.normal.background = texture;
}
```

It should end up like this:

```
public void OnGUI()
{
    if (this.modalStyle == null) {
        this.modalRect = new Rect(10, 10, Screen.width - 20, Screen.height - 20);
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        texture.SetPixel(0, 0, new Color(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f));
        texture.Apply();
        this.modalStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.window);
        this.modalStyle.normal.background = texture;
    }
    GUI.ModalWindow(
            this.GetHashCode(),
            this.modalRect,
            this.OnGUIDialog,
            this.DialogTitle,
            this.modalStyle);
}
```

They say they are going to fix this for the next update

Comment: Pode traduzir? Aqui é o StackOverflow em português.

Comment: Para corrigir temporariamente esse erro, altera a função OnGUI() de EditorFacebookMockDialog.cs.

Facebook corrigir o erro na próxima update.